# Custom datatable transformer for cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want to create custom datatable transformer in cucumber. This is how my feature looks like:

```
Given board
| o | _ | _ |
| o | _ | _ |
| o | _ | _ |
```

And I want to put it into custom object. Let's say that it looks like this:

```
class Board {

    private List<List<String>> board;

    public Board(List<List<String>> board) {
        this.board = board;
    }

}
```

My step definition should look like this:

```
@Given("^board$")
public void board(Board board) throws Throwable {
    // todo
}
```

Step definition works fine for `DataTable` class and `List<List<String>>`

```
@Given("^board$")
public void board(DataTable board) throws Throwable {
    // this works fine
}
```

And this also works fine

```
@Given("^board$")
public void board(List<List<String>> board) throws Throwable {
    // this also works fine
}
```

I tried to find a solution on the internet but without any success. I also tried to create `Transformer` but, as I see, it works fine only for strings (I want to use Datatable or List> at the input):

```
class BoardTransformer extends Transformer<Board> {

    @Override
    public Board transform(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your cucumber-JVM version?

Comment: I use 1.2.2 version.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: You should really upgrade your Cucumber!

Answer (score 4):

In cucumber 3.x you can use the `TypeRegistryConfigurer` to inform Cucumber how it should create `Board` objects from `DataTable`. Because you want to transform the whole table to a single object you have to use a `TableTransformer` rather then `TableCellTransformer`,`TableEntryTransformer` or `TableRowTransformer`.

You can place the `TypeRegistryConfigurer` anywhere on the glue path.

```
package io.cucumber.java.test;

import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistryConfigurer;
import io.cucumber.core.api.TypeRegistry;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableType;
import io.cucumber.datatable.TableTransformer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static java.util.Locale.ENGLISH;

public class TypeRegistryConfiguration implements TypeRegistryConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Locale locale() {
        return ENGLISH;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureTypeRegistry(TypeRegistry typeRegistry) {
        typeRegistry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(
            Board.class,
            (TableTransformer<Board>) table -> new Board(table.cells())));

    }

    static class Board {

        private final List<List<String>> board;

        private Board(List<List<String>> board) {
            this.board = board;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In older version of cucumber, as per your stated 1.2.2, you would have to request a list of your object as each row of the data table (from a feature file perspective) is seen as a different object e.g.

```
@Given("^board$")
public void board(List<Board> board) throws Throwable {
    // process however you want
}
```

a lot of cucumber has changed from v3 onwards regarding data tables e.g. switching from XStream to Jackson

but as previously advised, upgrade your Cucumber version if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you can go with

```
@Given("^board$")
public void board(List<List<String>> board) throws Throwable {
...
```

Why don't you just create your Board object right after

```
Board board2 = new Board(board);
```

It doen't look like you need a transformer.

Comment: A transformer is never "needed" it is just nicer and clearer to not clutter the code with technical details. Your answer does not help much ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the goal is to separate the "nasty parameter transform stuff" from the "actual test code", so that I can use nice objects in my test code, the best I have been able to come up with is to make use of Jackson ObjectMapper (or some other de/serialization lib that supports Map to Object).

For example:

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@When("I do some thing with input dataTable")
public void i_do_some_thing_with_input_dataTable(DataTable dataTable) {
    List<Map<String,String>> values = dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
    List<MyObject> inputs = values.stream().map(i -> objectMapper.convertValue(i,MyObject.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    inputs.forEach(i-> {
        //Do things with the input.
    });
}
```

You can/should ofcourse wrap this conversion in some nice service class that you can inject into / instantiate in your test.

This code assumes the following:

- you are using data tables with headers
- you have fields in `MyObject` with names that correspond to the headers in the table
- `MyObject` has appropriate getter/setters for each field.